# String XML constant not initialising value in xml file

Tags: android, android-xml

I have 37 gradient files. Rather than update the centreX value for all 37 files individually I thought it would bet better to store the value as a string constant in the strings.xml file and reference it in the layout xml. That way if I update the value in the string.xml all 37 individual layouts will automatically be updated.

The problem this, this isnt happening. Please see my two code snippets below:

```
 strings.xml
 <string name="gradient_size">70%</string>


 Layout file:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerColor="@color/white"
    android:endColor="@color/bored"
    android:startColor="@color/white"
    android:type="linear"
    android:centerX="@string/gradient_size"
    />
 </shape>
```

android:centerX="@string/gradient_size" is the string value of 70%.
But it doesnt work. If i remove the constant and just type android:centerX="70%" it works perfectly. But that means I would have to update all 37 files individually. Is there a simple reason the string value isnt working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring the constant as

```
<dimen name="gradient_size">75%</dimen>
```

instead of string makes this work. Hope it helps someone else.